# Android notification ProgressBar using AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, progress-bar, android-notifications

I've been trying to update my notification progress bar using `AsyncTask`, but somehow, it is not working. The progress always remains at zero and my application freezes. I guess, it was because of frequent data update to progress bar. So, I'm updating progress only in multiples of 5. I have tried all method, but none of them seems to be working. Here is my AsyncTask implementation:

```
private class ConnectToServerTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void> {
    NotificationManager mNotifyMgr;
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder;
    int mNotificationId;    

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        final TextView recLog=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.recLog);
        recLog.append("On pre-execute");

        mNotifyMgr = 
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        mBuilder= new NotificationCompat.Builder(getBaseContext())
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
        .setContentTitle("X-Files")
        .setContentText("Copy in progress")
        .setAutoCancel(true);
        mNotificationId = 001;
        mNotifyMgr.notify(mNotificationId, mBuilder.build());
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        final EditText ipText=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.ipText);
        try {
            serverIP=InetAddress.getByName(ipText.getText().toString());
            socket = new Socket(serverIP, 4444);
            if (socket != null) {
                InputStream min=socket.getInputStream();
                int filecount=min.read(); //read file count from server
                for (int j = 0; j < filecount; j++){
                    try {
                        InputStream in = socket.getInputStream();
                        int buffersize = socket.getReceiveBufferSize();
                        DataInputStream clientData = new DataInputStream(in);
                        String recFileName = clientData.readUTF(); // read file name
                        FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(
                                downloadFolderPath +"/" + recFileName);
                        byte[] buffer = new byte[buffersize];
                        long filesize = clientData.readLong(); // read file size
                        double nosofpackets=Math.ceil(((int) filesize)/buffer.length);
                        long z = filesize;
                        int n = 0;

                        int k=1;

                        while ((z > 0)
                                && (n = clientData.read(buffer, 0,
                                        (int) Math.min(buffer.length, z))) != -1) {
                            output.write(buffer, 0, n);
                            int progressint=(int)(k*100/nosofpackets);
                            publishProgress(progressint);
                            output.flush();
                            z -= n;
                        }
                        output.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer...values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
         if ((values[0])%5==0){
                mBuilder.setProgress(100, values[0], false);
                mNotifyMgr.notify(mNotificationId, mBuilder.build());
            }
    }       
}
```

Any help would be highly appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: and the background process is exucting all right???

Comment: Yes, the background code is executing alright. The stack trace says, "can't update view as it is not visible." Any idea?

Comment: can I see where are you declaring your progress bar...